# Running Git from command Line

Tags: java, git, cmd

I want to revert a merge by calling the 'git revert -m 1 ' command in cmd from Java. The code below reverts it and prints the output on console as OutputStream. I want a notification from Git in Java whether the revert is successful or not. How can I get it in say String or boolean format?

```
 public void revert(String path, String CommitId) throws IOException, Exception
    {

        String revertCommand="git revert -m 1 "+CommitId;
        String commitCommand="git commit -m "+'"'+"Reverted a commit"+'"';
        //revert the commit in that branch
        String[] command =
            {
                "cmd",
            };
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getErrorStream(), System.err)).start();
            new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getInputStream(), System.out)).start();
            PrintWriter stdin = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream());
            stdin.println(path);
            stdin.println("git checkout -b tempBranch release/2017.1");
            stdin.println(revertCommand);
            stdin.println(commitCommand);
            stdin.println("git push contrib/WMD-202817 tempBranch");
            // write any other commands you want here
            stdin.close();
            int returnCode = p.waitFor();
            System.out.println("Return code = " + returnCode);

    }


public class SyncPipe implements Runnable {
    public SyncPipe(InputStream istrm, OutputStream ostrm) {
          istrm_ = istrm;
          ostrm_ = ostrm;
      }
      public void run() {
          try
          {
              final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
              for (int length = 0; (length = istrm_.read(buffer)) != -1; )
              {
                  ostrm_.write(buffer, 0, length);
              }
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
      private final OutputStream ostrm_;
      private final InputStream istrm_;
}
```

Comment: Maybe `JGit` is more friendly for java applications. https://git-scm.com/book/be/v2/Embedding-Git-in-your-Applications-JGit. But I'm not sure if `git revert -m` is supported in JGit.

Comment: Its not. Hence using this method